# XC16 MCU family macros

Tags: pic, microchip, xc16, mplab-5.45, xc16-gcc-1.61

To detect a single MCU with XC16 we can use the defines such as `__dsPIC33EP128MC202__`, but what are the defines for a family such as `dsPIC33E`?

When googeling I find references to `__PIC24F__` etc, but none of them are defined within XC16. I can't find any define related to a whole family, only specific MCU:s.

I know I can add my own define to the project, but that would involve the human factor, remembering to set/update it correctly on each project. I figured if `__PIC24F__` is defined in ***a XC*** compiler, then XC16 would logically have the same system.

Answer (score 1):

```
#if defined(__dsPIC33E__)
```

works for me.   In a central header file I Have this :

```
#if defined(__dsPIC33F__)
#include "p33fxxxx.h"
#elif defined(__dsPIC33E__)
#include "p33exxxx.h"
#elif defined(__PIC24F__)
#include "p24fxxxx.h"
#endif
```

I think I got this from Microchips MLA libraries. I assume there is also a -H.   I do work with dspic33C, but that is a different codebase/repo since the peripherals are generally different